# SQL Server Agent Job Failing "Move-Item : access is denied"

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to refresh an Excel document and post it to a sharepoint site. I have tried to save the document onto the sharepoint site. I have tried to create a new drive that is rooted to the sharepoint site directory. Lastly, I have tried to upload the item using System.Net.Webclient.

Here is my code:

```
    $networklocation = "URL"
$filename = "FILEPATH.xlsx"
$fileforsharepoint = "FILEFORSHAREPOINT.XLSX"

# To view Excel file open need to set below property to True

$excel = new-object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

# Give delay to open
 Start-Sleep -s 5

# Open the Excel 
 $excelworkbook = $excel.workbooks.Open($filename, $null, $false)

 Start-Sleep -s 5

# This will Refresh All the pivot tables data.
 $excelworkbook.RefreshAll()
 Start-Sleep -s 5


 $excelworkbook.Save()
 $excelworkbook.SaveAS($fileforsharepoint)

 Start-Sleep -s 5

 $excel.quit()


 Start-Sleep -s 5

#New-PSDrive -Name "T" -Root $networklocation -PSProvider FileSystem

Move-item $fileforsharepoint $networklocation

##$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
##$webclient.UseDefaultCredentials=$true
##$webclient.UploadFile($networklocation + "/" + "FILEFORSHAREPOINT.xlsx", "PUT", $fileforsharepoint)
```

It will run in the powershell GUI. It will not run in a SQL Server management studio job.

> Failure message: Executed as user: USER. Name
>   Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                        ----
>   ---------     --------- --------      ----                        T                                      FileSystem    \$networklocation...        The job script
>   encountered the following errors. These errors did not stop the
>   script:  A job step received an error at line 4 in a PowerShell
>   script. The corresponding line is 'powershell.exe -File
>   '$filename'  '. Correct the script and reschedule
>   the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Move-item :
>   Access is denied  '  A job step received an error at line 4 in a
>   PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'powershell.exe -File
>   '$filename'  '. Correct the script and reschedule
>   the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'At
>   $filename:36 char:1    '  A job step received an
>   error at line 4 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is
>   'powershell.exe -File '$filename'. Correct the
>   script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by
>   PowerShell is: '+ Move-item $fileforsharepoint "T:"    '  A job step
>   received an error at line 4 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding
>   line is 'powershell.exe -File '$filename'.
>   Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information
>   returned by PowerShell is: '+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ' 
>   A job step received an error at line 4 in a PowerShell script. The
>   corresponding line is 'powershell.exe -File
>   '$filename'. Correct the script and reschedule
>   the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: '    +
>   CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: ($filename...and
>   Remove.     '  A job step received an error at line 4 in a PowerShell
>   script. The corresponding line is 'powershell.exe -File
>   '$filename'. Correct the script and reschedule
>   the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: '
>   xlsx:String) [Move-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException    '  A job step
>   received an error at line 4 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding
>   line is 'powershell.exe -File '$filename'.
>   Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information
>   returned by PowerShell is: '    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   MoveItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerS     '  A job step
>   received an error at line 4 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding
>   line is 'powershell.exe -File '$filename'.
>   Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information
>   returned by PowerShell is: '   hell.Commands.MoveItemCommand    '  A
>   job step received an error at line 4 in a PowerShell script. The
>   corresponding line is 'powershell.exe -File
>   '$filename'. Correct the script and reschedule
>   the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: '     '. 
>   Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.

Before you suggest the fix for the Excel bug (create the folder in the C: path), I have already done that. Seems to be an Excel related issue, but I am stumped on how to upload this file.

Comment: Could account permissions be an issue? Your SQL Server / SQL Server Job Agent would likely be runnig under different accounts. In my experience "Access is denied " errors are to do with account permissions.

Comment: @Alex It definitely could. However, I don't know what permissions I need to give more of. I have full control on my account and the account on the server has full control. I tried running the job through SQL Server MGMT on the server and it failed as well.

Comment: SQL Server / SQL Server Job agents run under their own accouts. If you go to SQL Server Configuration manager (or Windows Services) and find out what accounts they are running under. For testing purposes you can change the service to run under your user account.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Services, find SQL Server Agent. See what it says Log on as.
2. Right click on folder, properties, security, add, type in that Log on as. give it full permissions.

Now SQL JOB can move files with powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Create these two folders on windows. Ms Excel has a bug to manage SQL Agent Service if you do not have these folders on your server. After manny months, almost an year trying to solve this issue I finally solved doing this.

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop